# MySQL error 2003 over ssh tunnel when replicating, not when using client

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-replication

I am trying to set up replication on a MySQL server over an SSH tunnel. I've set up a port forward on the slave from port 7777 at localhost to port 3306 on the master, and I can connect to my replication account using

```
mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 7777 -u replicate -p
```

However, when I set the master configuration on the slave (using host 127.0.0.1, user replicate, the correct password [double-checked it], and port 7777), it has an error connecting to the master with code 2003, which seems to be associated with login problems. I checked the permissions, and 'replicate'@'127.0.0.1' has replication slave on *.*. Why can I connect with a client, but replication is failing.

EDIT:

The master server runs MySQL 5.1.66 on Ubuntu 10.04; the slave runs MySQL 5.5.28 on Fedora 16.

```
mysql --ssl --help
```

results in:

```
Variables (--variable-name=value)
and boolean options {FALSE|TRUE}  Value (after reading options)
--------------------------------- -----------------------------
auto-rehash                       TRUE
character-sets-dir                (No default value)
column-type-info                  FALSE
comments                          FALSE
compress                          FALSE
debug-check                       FALSE
debug-info                        FALSE
database                          (No default value)
default-character-set             latin1
delimiter                         ;
vertical                          FALSE
force                             FALSE
named-commands                    FALSE
ignore-spaces                     FALSE
local-infile                      FALSE
no-beep                           FALSE
host                              (No default value)
html                              FALSE
xml                               FALSE
line-numbers                      TRUE
unbuffered                        FALSE
column-names                      TRUE
sigint-ignore                     FALSE
port                              3306
prompt                            mysql>
quick                             FALSE
raw                               FALSE
reconnect                         TRUE
socket                            /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
ssl                               TRUE
ssl-ca                            (No default value)
ssl-capath                        (No default value)
ssl-cert                          (No default value)
ssl-cipher                        (No default value)
ssl-key                           (No default value)
ssl-verify-server-cert            FALSE
table                             FALSE
user                              (No default value)
safe-updates                      FALSE
i-am-a-dummy                      FALSE
connect_timeout                   0
max_allowed_packet                16777216
net_buffer_length                 16384
select_limit                      1000
max_join_size                     1000000
secure-auth                       FALSE
show-warnings                     FALSE
```

Slave status:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
--------------
show slave status
--------------

*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 127.0.0.1
                  Master_User: replicate
                  Master_Port: 7777
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 397
               Relay_Log_File: slave-relay-bin.000004
                Relay_Log_Pos: 107
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error:
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 107
              Relay_Log_Space: 107
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 2003
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replicate@127.0.0.1:7777' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error:
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

EDIT:

SELinux is enabled on the server, and is in enforce mode.

Comment: I believe, on the slave machine, after you setup the ssh tunnel, you should be using `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 7777  -u replicate -p` to connect to master. Does that work?

Comment: That's what I meant, not `-P 3306`. `-P 7777` does work, but the replication still does not.

Comment: On the Master machine, does `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u replicate -p` work??

Comment: That command does work.

Comment: Tyr following (1) On master `telnet localhost 3306` (2) On Slave `telnet localhost 7777`. Post the output. No need to login.

Comment: Slave: `5.1.66-0ubuntu0.10.04.3-log+Q,l_tMc)NB@Xy{}",WQrConnection closed by foreign host.
`; Master: `5.1.66-0ubuntu0.10.04.3-logWQ$1h=5159Ty(W\`Z#<E'0Connection closed by foreign host.
`

Comment: You may have ssl enabled. Post `mysql --ssl --help`. If so, try disable it in your `my.cnf`. If that helps I will move it to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very likely your mysqld connection to a 7777 port is blocked by selinux. To allow that, do following

```
semanage port -a -t mysqld_port_t -p tcp 7777
```

To check if it is added to mysqld allowed port

```
semanage port -l | grep mysqld_port_t
```

Comment: I don't see any SSL-related options enables in my.cnf. When I actually connect from master with `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 --ssl -u replicate -p` and type `\s`, it says `SSL: Not in use`. The only place it seems to indicate that SSL might be used is in the variables list from `--help`.

Comment: What OS are you using? (redhat/Centos/Ubuntu/Debian??) Also post output of `mysql -v -h 127.0.0.1 -P 7777 -u replicate -p`. Let see if that give more hint.

Comment: Master is on Ubuntu 10.04, slave on Fedora 16.

Comment: What about output of `mysql -v -h 127.0.0.1 -P 7777 -u replicate -p`?

Comment: What do you mean by "post the output"? When I run it on the slave server, it logs in successfully to the master server. It shows trademark boilerplate, but the only non-generic info shown is `Server version: 5.1.66-0ubuntu0.10.04.3-log (Ubuntu)` and `reading history-file /home/cpast/.mysql_history`. It also brings up a mysql prompt.

Comment: But you said replicate does not work, is it working now? The `-v` make mysql print more debug info.

Comment: Still not working. I added `show slave status` output to the question.

Comment: On slave box, do `grep 1 /selinux/enforce`, if it show `1`, do `semanage port -l | grep 3306`, and post out put here.

Comment: I updated the answer, give it a try.